# How to Check Embedded font in PDF using iText

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I would like to check the Embedded fonts in the PDF using Itext/Itextsharp

i have used the Itexthsarp to get the fonts from the PDF,below code to get the font collection of the PDF
            bool embeededFont = false;

```
       iTextSharpLGPV.PdfReader reader = new iTextSharpLGPV.PdfReader(fileName);
        HashSet<String> names = new HashSet<string>();
        iTextSharpLGPV.PdfDictionary resources;
        for (int p = 1; p <= reader.NumberOfPages; p++)
        {
            iTextSharpLGPV.PdfDictionary dic = reader.GetPageN(p);
            resources = dic.GetAsDict(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Resources);
            if (resources != null)
            {
                //gets fonts dictionary
                iTextSharpLGPV.PdfDictionary fonts = resources.GetAsDict(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Font);
                if (fonts != null)
                {

                    iTextSharpLGPV.PdfDictionary font;

                    foreach (iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName key in fonts.Keys)
                    {
                        font = fonts.GetAsDict(key);
                        string name = font.GetAsName(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Basefont).ToString();

                        //check for prefix subsetted font

                        if (name.Length > 8 && name.ToCharArray()[7] == '+')
                        {
                            name = String.Format("{0} subset ({1})", name.Substring(8), name.Substring(1, 7));

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            //get type of fully embedded fonts
                            name = name.Substring(1);
                            iTextSharpLGPV.PdfDictionary desc = font.GetAsDict(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Fontdescriptor);
                            if (desc == null)
                                name += "no font descriptor";
                            else if (desc.Get(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Fontfile) != null)
                                name += "(Type1) embedded";
                            else if (desc.Get(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Fontfile2) != null)
                                name += "(TrueType) embedded ";
                            else if (desc.Get(iTextSharpLGPV.PdfName.Fontfile3) != null)
                                name += name;//("+font.GetASName(PdfName.SUBTYPE).ToString().SubSTring(1)+")embedded';
                        }

                        names.Add(name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: ... and what exactly is the question?

Comment: how to check the font is embedded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*As clarified in a comment, the OP wants to know **how to check the font is embedded**.*

Please have a look at the section *Embedded Font Programs* in the PDF specifications, e.g. at section 9.9 in the older ISO 32000-1:

> Table 126 summarizes the ways in which font programs shall be embedded in a PDF file, depending on the representation of the font program. The key shall be the name used in the font descriptor to refer to the font file stream; the subtype shall be the value of the **Subtype** key, if present, in the font file stream dictionary. Further details of specific font program representations are given below.
>
> **Table 126 – Embedded font organization for various font types**
>
> Key -
>   Subtype -
>   Description
>
> **FontFile** -
>   **—** -
>   Type 1 font program, in the original (noncompact) format described in *Adobe Type 1 Font Format*. This entry may appear in the font descriptor for a **Type1** or **MMType1** font dictionary.
>
> **FontFile2** -
>   **—** -
>   (PDF 1.1) TrueType font program, as described in the *TrueType Reference Manual*. This entry may appear in the font descriptor for a **TrueType** font dictionary or (PDF 1.3) for a **CIDFontType2CIDFont** dictionary.
>
> **FontFile3** -
>   **Type1C** -
>   (PDF 1.2) Type 1–equivalent font program represented in the Compact Font Format (CFF), as described in Adobe Technical Note #5176, *The Compact Font Format Specification*. This entry may appear in the font descriptor for a **Type1** or **MMType1** font dictionary.
>
> **FontFile3** -
>   **CIDFontType0C** -
>   (PDF 1.3) Type 0 CIDFont program represented in the Compact Font Format (CFF), as described in Adobe Technical Note #5176, *The Compact Font Format Specification*. This entry may appear in the font descriptor for a **CIDFontType0** CIDFont dictionary.
>
> **FontFile3** -
>   **OpenType** -
>   (PDF 1.6) OpenType® font program, as described in the *OpenType Specification v.1.4* (see the Bibliography). OpenType is an extension of TrueType that allows inclusion of font programs that use the Compact Font Format (CFF). ...

Thus, you should look for these keys in the **FontDescriptor** dictionary of the respective font, i.e. essentially what you did in your code with `desc`.